# How to open a modal using angular (without ui bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying to make make the modal appear, but have failed to do so after multiple attempts.

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<!-- Login modal -->   
<div class="modal fade" id="login_2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLogin" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content modal-popup">
                <a href="#" class="close-link"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
                <form action="#" class="popup-form" id="myLogin">
                    <div class="login_icon"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Username">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Password">
                    <div class="text-left">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End modal -->
```

What I want to do is to load this modal automatically if a certain variable is set in `$stateParams` in the controller. Otherwise, it should remain hidden. I have tried `angular.element('login_2').modal()` without success

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-show` [link to documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

You can make something like:

```
<div class="modal fade" ng-show="showMyModal" ...
```

And a checkbox for controlling it (but you can do anything)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showMyModal">
```

Remember that you can animate ngShow with ngAnimate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using an existing library (that isn't ui bootstrap), I recommend [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog). You can use custom HTML templates and styles and it's just for creating modals.

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle it like this.

```
$('#login_2').modal('show');
```